# How to run task every 5 seconds in background thread without block UI in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, background, nstimer

I'm working on the chat app, in chat screen my app need to check new message every 5s. I want to do that in background thread so my app will be not blocked UI. I tried the code below but when user typing the message, the UI seems to be blocked. Also, I cannot fire this task when user exit the chat screen.

This is my code I tried:

`getLatestMessagesWithInterval()` is called in `viewwillAppear()`

```
-(void) getLatestMessagesWithInterval
{

    NSLog(@"GET MESSAGE INTERVAL");
    [self retrieveLatestChatMessages];

    // Call this method again using GCD
    dispatch_queue_t q_background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, q_background, ^(void){
        [self getLatestMessagesWithInterval];
    });

}




 -(void) retrieveLatestChatMessages
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"]) {
        NSDictionary * userDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"SessionDictionary"];
        .....

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            [[LSDataManager sharedDataManager] getLatestMessagesWithAuthKey:authenKey andLimit:limit withBlock:^ (NSDictionary* responseDict)
             {
                 if (responseDict) {
                     [self loadDataFromServer:responseDict];

                     NSArray* lastMessageArray= nil;

                     //filter message data
                     if (self.MessagesArray.count >0) {

                        //perform data

                             self.TempdataSource = [[[ContentManager sharedManager] generateConversation:lastMessageArray withSenderID:self.senderID] mutableCopy];

                             //compare 2 arrays
                             if ([self.TempdataSource count] == [self.dataSource count]) {
                                 NSLog(@"both are same");
                             }
                             else{
                                 NSLog(@"both are different");
                                 self.dataSource = [self.TempdataSource mutableCopy];


                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
                                     //Add method, task you want perform on mainQueue
                                     [self refreshMessages];
                                 });

                             }

                         }
                     }
                 }
             }];
        });
    }

}
```

I have called `retrieveLatestChatMessages()` to get message from server. the server will return in block. After performing the data, I reload tableview in main thread. Pls. help me to correct it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Communicate with API asynchronously for example use AFNetworking and your UI will not be blocked, also you can set timer for every second and call something like that

```
if (numberOfSeconds % 5 == 0) {
     numberOfSeconds = 0;
     retrieveLatestChatMessages()
}
```

Comment: i have used AFnetworking to communicate with API. My issue is when i run the code above, the UI seem to be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

### Two options

### *Option 1*

Call that method every 5 seconds using NSTimer.

*I would recommend not to use it.*

### *Option 2*

Have an app TCP based for chat messages.

This would be best option for chat messages.

---

### Edit 1

learn how to use TCP as per your language. For iOS TCP follow link

http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sites/default/files/Socket_Programing_for_IOS.pdf

Comment: Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @user3884889 : learn how to use TCP as per your language. For iOS TCP follow link  http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sites/default/files/Socket_Programing_for_IOS.pdf